# Как завершить код по нажатию клавиши? (Си)

Tags: c

Как можно завершить код по нажатию клавиши ESC?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>



void invertDigit(unsigned int a,unsigned int b) {
   
    while (a!=0) {
          b=b*10+a%10;
          a=a/10;
          }
    
    printf("Результат:%d\n",b);    
}
int main() 
{
    unsigned int a,b=0;
    printf("Number:");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    invertDigit(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Решения зависят от платформы (сочетание среды разработки и целевой ОС).. В POSIX совместимых можно реализовать с помощью библиотеки ncurses. Нужно конкретнее определить цель.

Comment: Вы хотите прервать чтение в функции `scanf()`? Остальные варианты не имеют смысла, нигде кроме scanf вы просто не успеете нажать ESC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Именно Esc? И именно завершить — т.е., как я понимаю, вы просто хотите, чтоб после всей работы окно консоли не закрывалось, пока не нажмете Esc?

Раз вы подключаете `conio.h`, то он у вас есть :), так что напишите перед последним `return`

```
while(_getch()!=27);
```

Т.е. игнорировать все клавиши, кроме Esc, код которой 27? и при нажатии на нее завершить цикл.

Answer (score -1):

Для завершения ввода с терминала, в Люних принят код Ctr/D.
В принципе, это можно изменить с помощью параметра *eof =* команды *stty*. Но это породит немалый гемморой... Вы уверены, что оно Вам надо?